# How to set variables in tmux.conf that do *not* get exported to the environment, while referencing them in tmux?

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

I have the following content in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
FG_COLOR=blue
BG_COLOR=white
# Many lines ...
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style fg=$FG_COLOR,bg=$BG_COLOR
```

This has the advantage that identical values only need to be written once in the config file. However I don't like it that these values are seen in the shell running in tmux (they pop up in `env` output). These values are entirely useless outside of the context of tmux, so I'd prefer they not show up.

I have tried the following settings, but *all* of them result in tmux complaining `bad style` or similar:

```
@FG_COLOR=blue
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style fg=@FG_COLOR
```

```
set-option -g @FG_COLOR blue
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style fg=@FG_COLOR
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style "fg=#{FG_COLOR}"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of user options looks like this:

```
set -g @FG_COLOR blue
set -g window-status-current-style "fg=#{@FG_COLOR}"
```

They are normal options with the difference that their name starts with an `@`. So you need both when using them: the `@` in front of the name as well as the `#{}`.

Even with tmux >= 3.2, I think that this is a nicer solution than using `%hidden`.

I am not sure when exactly they were introduced but according to `CHANGES` they existed already in 2.2:

> CHANGES FROM 2.2 TO 2.3, 29 September 2016
> [...]
>
> - 'set -a' for appending to user options (@foo) is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

If your tmux is new enough you can use `%local`. You may need 3.2 or master however.

Edit: it is actually called `%hidden` and is available from 3.2.

Comment: Any solutions with 3.0a?

Comment: @iBug Maybe `set-environment -gu FG_COLOR` and such at the end of `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: Looks like I have to resort to manually un-setting them at the end of the config file before I get tmux 3.2. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also I mean `%hidden` not `%local`, sorry. It was originally called local but I changed it! But yes it will not be available until 3.2.

Comment: Is there a changelog or docs about this? Also, does tmux.conf has any formal like grammar?